# Modbus TCP Response Time

Tags: tcp, modbus, modbus-tcp

I have use modbus tcp on m3 core and using lwip stack on lower layers.
When I send ,read holding registers(125 register) command on modbus poll to mcu and watch request and response frames on wireshark, values are;

Handshake[SYN+ACK] frame after receiving [SYN] frame   = 400us
Average Response Time Modbus/TCP by MCU = 900 us - 1.5ms

I think Handshake response is normal, but ı am not sure Modbus/TCP response time. Is it OK ?
Baudrate is 100Mbit.
Thank you all,

Comment: Hello, could you please explain how did you calculate the average response time ? Is there a statictical tool that enable us to match query and responses by modbus tcp transation ID ?
best regards

Comment: Wireshark shows "response time" of every modbus TCP response frame .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time is ok for typical modbus tcp server